# Как добавить задание ЕГЭ в базу данных на C#?

Tags: база-данных

Здравствуйте!
Есть необходимость в добавлении задания (рис. ниже) ЕГЭ в базу данных
[image: задание варианта ЕГЭ]

Пришла мысль о создании редактора заданий как на этом сайте создаются вопросы. А потом все это перевести в тип данных BLOB и засунуть в БД (рис. ниже)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На сколько удачная идея? Как сложно создать такую вещь? В C# имею базовые знания. Если неудачная идея, то как лучше реализовать добавление в базу данных подобных заданий, содержащих рисунки, текст, таблицы?
Спасибо!

Comment: В оригинале этим задания содержатся в MS Word документах определённого формата, которые лежат в BLOB столбцах.

Comment: Зависит от того, какова цель. Если потом по этой базе кто-то тестироваться будет, то может лучше использовать готовое решение вроде Moodle? Я, когда писала систему тестирования, просто хранила текст задания отдельно, рисунки к заданию отдельно в blob.